# How to write a GUI library using OpenGL?

Tags: user-interface, opengl, graphics

I am looking for a book that discusses about how to write a GUI libray.

Comment: Just a small note, ever thought about using Clutter?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother reinventing the wheel. It will probably end up being a square one.
Rather use widget APIs like Gtk+ or Qt. Both APIs allows you to create widgets which are drawn with OpenGL-enabled 'painters'. That means that you can use Qt and Gtk widgets just like usual, only within an OpenGL context. The whole process is completely transparent after the initial boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of design you might want to look at the [design patterns book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-patterns-elements-reusable-object-oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1257248984&sr=8-1). This uses the design of a Windowing system for many examples.

You might also want to refer to other OpenGL GUI libraries, e.g.

- [What is the best free cross-platform OpenGL GUI library for a video game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211018/what-is-the-best-free-cross-platform-opengl-gui-library-for-a-video-game)